# .gitignore added to project and now it won't run

Tags: reactjs, github

So I have ReactJS project that is on GitHub and I'm new to this so I didn't have a .gitignore file so someone did a pull request adding it and I accepted and merged. I pulled that back to my local version and now I can't npm start my project bc there aren't any node modules anymore. I am sure there is an easy way of handling this, but what are you supposed to do? It seems like the node modules have been deleted so how can the app run?

Answer (score 2):

Run `npm install`. Afterwards all modules will be installed. This requires a valid `package.json` file. It is best practise not to push the node modules to your repository since they consume a lot of space.

Comment: Thank you and this makes a lot more sense. If I have other dependencies like react-router etc. do I need to install all of those again as well or when I npm install does it read the package.json and automatically install these as well?

Comment: @PurplePanda When you run `npm install`, npm looks for dependencies in the `package.json` and installs all of them (as well as sub-dependencies). So you don't need to install them manually.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add on to @PurplePanda's answer. Since you didn't have a `.gitignore` file initially, your node_modules folder would have been committed as well. In order for the `.gitignore` file to now correctly ignore the `node_modules`, it had to first be removed. You just need to run `npm install` locally and you should be good to go.

Comment: Thank you and this makes a lot more sense. If I have other dependencies like react-router etc. do I need to install all of those again as well or when I npm install does it read the package.json and automatically install these as well?

Comment: Yes, `npm install` will install whatever is specified in your `package.json` file.